# JavaFX assign mouse event handler to Arc

Tags: java, javafx, automatic-ref-counting, mouse

I have a Arc, and like to assign event handler in the controller class.
I build a JFXPanel inside Swing JPanel.
The panel I initialized as follow:

```
    public void init()
    {
       Platform.runLater( new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run()   {
       try {
         FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader( getClass().getResource("fxml.fxml" ));
         Pane myPane = (Pane) loader.load();
         controller = loader.getController();
         Scene scene = new Scene( myPane );
         setScene( scene );
      }
      catch ( Exception e ) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }  
    }
  }); 
 }
```

In a Controller class:
I declare arc with the same name on my FXML file.

```
    @FXMLprivate Arc   arc;
```

in initialize method I did:

```
    @FXML
    protected void initialize()
    {
        arc.setOnMouseClicked( new EventHandler<Event>() {

        @Override
        public void handle( Event event )
        {
            System.out.println("Evento");
        }
    } );
```

But, the event  is not fired.

Comment: This question is similar to: [How to detect MouseClick on the “stroke” part of a QuadCurve?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18846227/how-to-detect-mouseclick-on-the-stroke-part-of-a-quadcurve).  The code is also similar and works in the linked QuadCurve case.

Comment: In your code you have `@FXMLprivate`, with no space between `@FXML` and `private`, you need a space between those two words otherwise the FXML loader cannot initalize the arc member.